# Change URL opened by Eclipse when running web application project on Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications

I have the following setup:

- Eclipse dynamic web application project
- Tomcat 7 configured as Server in Eclipse Mars
- https running on port 8443

Now, right clicking *Project -> Run as -> Run on Server* will start the Tomcat and open the URL "http://localhost:8080/mywebapp" via external browser. This is nice but I need to open the URL with **HTTPS** scheme, i.e. "https://localhost:8443/mywebapp". Anyone knows how to configure that in Eclipse? I thought it must be possible to change the startup URL but couldn't find an option, nor something on SO.

Similar questions and their answers suggest to make the web.xml with security constraint and transport garantuee set to CONFIDENTIAL but I don't want to change the web.xml because it would be different in production environment.

I also tried to make Tomcat redirect from HTTP 8080 to HTTPS 8443 but it seems to be not possible.

Comment: Do you need SSL or not? If you need SSL, it's not just matter of changing ports, but whole lot of other stuff. It's also not uncommon to setup SSL on apache and proxy it to Tomcat. BTW, preffered way of starting app in Eclipse on Tomcat is to start Tomcat in debug mode (servers view, Debug) and then drag/drop your web project onto server. Also clicking Open on server gives you options to change ports and other stuff.

Comment: I already have configured SSL, as I wrote in my setup. I just want to know how I can make Eclipse to start not the default URL when I start my web app via Eclipse but using a custom URL to directly jump on the HTTPS-URL of my web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to accomplish this, but it will involve creating a script.
If you are on a windows machine, then you can do this with a batch file; otherwise a shell script will do for linux flavors.

1) Create an empty script for now - somewhere on your file system (e.g. run_https_url.sh or run_https_url.bat)

2) Open your Eclipse and goto Preferences -> General -> Web Browser

Switch the radio to "Use external web browser" and Click on "New..."

[image]

Now you are going to create your own custom web browser that points to the script you created in step 1)

**Name**: Whatever you want (I called mine My HTTPS Browser)

**Location**: Path to your script (I'm on a mac so I created a shell script)

**Parameters**: Make sure you put %URL% (**Important**)

[image]

Click OK and Apply to set it and exit out of there.

3) Craft your script according to your needs. I will not provide the full script since I don't know what environment you are running in, but this will get you started and get you to the result you want.

For my run_https_url.sh I'm using the following (w/ chrome):

```
url="$1"  ## This holds the %URL% paramter set in Eclipse
open -a "Google Chrome" $url
```

Here is an example in batch (w/ chrome):

```
set url=%1  
start chrome %url%
```

At this point, I would test the running of the app from within Eclipse just as a sanity check to make sure that the setup so far is correct.

Of course, this is just a straight proxy and does not use https nor does it use another port number. This is where you will have to craft your script with the appropriate string manipulations.

**Example**: Break down the URL into domain, port, path, etc. and add on the https and the port number, then call it with the url and the browser you desire.

Good luck. I hope that helps.

Comment: This is the solution. According to the answers given, Eclipse does not provide any mechanism to change the start up URL per web app, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way for it, in `conf\server.xml` find

```
`<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>`
```

which is used by default, comment it and un comment the one below it

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Also, you need to setup a keystore.
See:[configure Tomcat to support SSL or https](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/)

Comment: My HTTPS is already running. I want to know how I can make Eclipse start the web app with that HTTPS-URL. (see comment on question)

Comment: Will this redirect from 8080 to 8443 automatically? Because I tried that earlier and it didn't work.